# display a specified index of a pointer char*

Tags: c

I am trying to point on a specified character in a string contained on a structure
here my code

```
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int age;
}PERSON, *person;

int main(){
    person serenity;
    serenity = (person)malloc(sizeof(PERSON));
    strcpy(&(serenity->name),"Serenity");
   printf("%c",*(&(serenity->name)+1));
}
```

here i wanted to display the second character which is 'e' but it shows 'n' instead
anyone can explain me what is wrong with this,
thank you

Comment: `strcpy(&(serenity->name),"Serenity");` I really doubt that's what you want to do. Even if you had written `strcpy(serenity->name,"Serenity");` you still haven't allocated any memory to hold the string.

Comment: I just wanted to copy the string "serenity" into the name of this person

Comment: @SerenityTn - for that you need to allocate memory for `char *name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not allocated memory for `name`

```
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int age;
}PERSON, *person;

int main(){
    person serenity;
    serenity = malloc(sizeof(PERSON));
    serenity->name = malloc(sizeof("Serenity")); //<< Missing
    strcpy((serenity->name),"Serenity");
    printf("%c",*((serenity->name)+1)); // << Also you want the value in pointer name NOT its address
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs `e`. Also since you tagged `C` there is no need to cast the return type of malloc.

Comment: There is actually no need for the `+1` in the `sizeof` serenity, since this is a string literal with a null terminating character appended automatically that is included in the sizeof result. Also, I believe that your first `malloc` call isn't doing what it's supposed to do...

Comment: @Streppel - Yeah thanks for pointing that out - it was a typo actually.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
serenity = (person)malloc(sizeof(PERSON));
```

allocates the structure

```
typedef struct{
   char *name;
   int age;
}PERSON
```

however name is kept uninitialized and points somewhere in memory causing a crash when you copy to it.

So instead of

```
strcpy(&(serenity->name),"Serenity");
```

write

```
serenity->name = strdup("Serenity");
```

which is the same as

```
serenity->name = malloc(strlen("Serenity")+1);
strcpy(serenity->name,"Serenity");
```

don't forget to free that string as well later.

Comment: Just be aware that strdup is a POSIX function, therefore not a standard function.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, okay... All of those answers aside, if you do not aim to change the characters inside the string `"Serenity"` in the future, you could just do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    const char *name;   // <-- added const
    int age;
}PERSON, *person;

int main( ){
    person serenity;
    serenity = (person) malloc( sizeof( PERSON ) );
    serenity->name = "Serenity";    // <-- simply assigned the pointer with the
                                    // address to the array of constant characters
    printf( "%c", *( serenity->name + 1 ) );    // <-- changed this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `printf("%c",*(serenity->name+1));`, also do `strcpy(serenity->name,"Serenity");`.

If you have a pointer `char* name;` you access the second element by doing `name[1]` or `*(name+1)`. `&name` will give you the address where the pointer address of `name` is stored. This is not what you want here.

Another issue in your program is that you never allocate memory for the variable `name`. You need a `serenity->name = (char*)malloc(128);`. But using an arbitrary length like 128 is very dangerous in combination with `strcpy`. Use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` to work around this.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried this way but the whole program crushed it doesn't run :(

Comment: You also need to allocate memory for `name`. See updated answer.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` as sometimes it does not actually output a string. `snprintf` would be preferable, if you don't actually allocate exactly how much you need as in the accepted answer.